# Draw a Clickable Square?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C# but I have a lot of Java experience so I've been told that C# is fairly easy to comprehend based on that.

So far it is. At the moment though, I want to make a simple TicTacToe as part of an exercise. However what I want to do, is draw clickable squares that I can reference so I can check if the box is already clicked or not.

I am currently using Visual Studio Express 2012. I am making a Windows Form Application for Desktop usage.

I looked around for solutions but I can't seem to find something that does this.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hi Vipar. Can you please add some more info on what you're using to develop this exercise? Windows Forms, WPF, maybe Windows Phone...?

Comment: to what your application targets ? desktop or web application ?

Comment: Ah right, I forgot about that!

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or WPF? You should tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I think that should do it

Comment: You could use a PictureBox from the ToolBox, then double click it and you will raise a Picturebox clicked event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
internal sealed class Box : Control
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, new Size(Width - 1, Height - 1)));
    }

    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You Clicked The Box!");
    }
}
```

Create a class that derives from `Control`. From here you can override a whole bunch of virtual members including the `OnPaint` method where you can perform all of your drawing logic. It's all very intuitive with the assistance of IntelliSense (DrawRectangle, Draw Line etc).

If you want you can override `OnClick` like I did here but otherwise you can subscribe to an the controls' `Click` event just as you would a standard control.

You can also derive from `ContainerControl` for your 'grid' which will behave similarly to a Panel or GroupBox control.

Here's a quick example I just put together to get you started. The border is a tiny bit bugged at some resolutions, I'll leave that down to my abysmal mathematics skills.

```
internal sealed class GameGrid : ContainerControl
{
    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                GameButton button = new GameButton
                {
                    Width = Width/3,
                    Height = Height/3,
                };

                button.Location = new Point(x*button.Width++, y*button.Height++);
                Controls.Add(button);

                button.Click += button_Click;
            }
        }
    }

    static void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GameButton gameButton = (GameButton)sender;
        gameButton.CircleCheck = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Location, new Size(Width - 1, Height - 1)));
    }
}

internal sealed class GameButton : Control
{
    private bool _cricleCheck;
    public bool CircleCheck 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _cricleCheck;
        } 
        set 
        {
            _cricleCheck = value;
            Invalidate();
        } 
    }

    private readonly Pen circlePen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2.0f);

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Location, new Size(Width - 1, Height - 1)));

        if (CircleCheck)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(circlePen, new Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Location.X + 10, ClientRectangle.Location.Y + 10, Width - 30, Height - 30));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common clickable square is a [button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx).

If the button is clickable in the current gamestate and what icon should be presented there if it was clicked sounds like a job for your background logic.

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to use buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Create a new Form
- Drop a PictureBox control inside the form in order to render the Tic Tac Toe board
- Handle the Paint event to do the graphics rendering
- Handle the MouseClick event to detect if the user has clicked inside the board and use the event arguments to determine on which of the 9 squares of the board the user has clicked

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar exercise 2days ago,

Just check this tutorial, it will be enough I guess:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2400/Tic-Tac-Toe-in-C

And for the Square you can either use buttons or you could use PictureBox like this tutorial (although they used vb.net not c# but it's easy to translate):

http://vbprogramming.8k.com/tutorials/tic-tac-toe.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is using simple buttons with background color or image. 
Have a variable for currently playing user and change

```
button.Text
```

on click event. 
Set all button texts for "" at the beginning- that way you can check if the button was clicked:

```
if (button.Text!="") 
     //it was already clicked
```